# php changed list boxes only

Tags: php, listbox

I am having a form with quite a lot of list boxes. After submitting the form I have no problem to process all list boxes with PHP in a loop. But I am looking for a way to only grab those that have changed because it would save a lot of processing time.

Let's say I have a hundred list boxes. Their ids are "lb_1" ... "lb_100". I would loop through them like:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
   if (substr($key,0,3)== "lb_" ) {
      ...do something...
   }
}
```

That loop however will do something with all the hundred listbox values. I only want to catch those that have actually changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the only way you can do this is using javascript on the client-side to only send the changed boxes.

Comment: Well, when the user visits the page with all the form elements, they are rendered with specific values. That means that you have access to the values in PHP. So, can't you just pull the original values from e.g. your database and then check them against what is being submitted in your $_POST-array?

Comment: Hi hurrtz, that is actually what I am doing now. I compare all listbox values with what's in the databse and only if different then I set the new value in the database. I just want to save all the compare operations.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the suggestion given by @Tushar, you could use Javascript to set the Disabled attribute to true for any field that has not changed. That way they would not exist in the POST. The only way you would know which ones to disable is to store the initial values (in JS probably for ease of comparison). Then on form submit, loop through the fields and disable all the ones that have not changed.

```
document.getElementById('lb_1').disabled = true;  // example of how to disable field
```

I can provide more example code if you like.

Comment: Hi Revent, thanks for that idea. I will try that. I actually tried to use the onchange event to change the name of the listbox hoping that only those names can be caught by the PHP loop. Obviously the $_POST array only contains the original names. Client side renaming is not passed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to your tips I came up with this client-side solution:

I added a hidden form text field right before each listbox that contains the original value. The hidden field and the list boxed are named with the same unique suffix so I know which one belongs to which.

When the form is passed the PHP loop looks like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
   if (substr($key,0,3)== "lb_" ) {
      if ($_POST[hidden_name] != $value) {
         setNewValue($value);
      }
   }
}
```

This is a lot faster than accessing the database for each compare since the values are already available in the $_POST array.

Thanks for your help.